# setting core-ajax development/production url with grunt

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs, yeoman, polymer

I am trying to build a *Polymer* webapp that relies on REST APIs based on a *Node.js* backend.
I have scaffolded my project with *Yeoman* and using *Mongoskin* to create a RESTful interface with the backend.

I am using the *core-ajax* element passing it my *localhost* url when I am developing, however every time I deploy to *heroku* I have to change this url to connect to the right backend APIs.

I believe I can access the *process.env.NODE_ENV* variable only backend side, therefore I am asking if there is a way to tell grunt to change this url when I build my *dist* folder.

The only option I have in mind is:

- Create a *globals-element* with the url
- Setting the production url in this element in the index.html
- Setting the localhost url in this element in a new development.html that I will use while testing locally
- Exclude development.html the during the grunt build

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Scott through together a mock-ajax to show how one could use core-ajax with mock data: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/mock-ajax. You may be able to adapt something like that for local dev.